# Сделать привязку функции скрипта на клик по дополнительной функциональной кнопке мышки

Tags: python, python-3.x, мышь

Необходимо забиндить пятую кнопку мыши (Mouse5), которая сбоку, на вызов определенной функции.

С модулем keyboard уже разобрался. Не могу понять какой код у пятой кнопки мыши.. Не принимает никакие: ни mouse5, ни key5 и др.. В папке с модулем нашел файлы, в которых явно можно было увидеть, что он может обрабатывать нажатия и передвижения мыши. Но все переменные, которые там были не принимаются..

Может ли кто-то помочь мне с этим? И есть ли альтернативные решения этого вопроса? Мне нужно просто чтобы по нажатию кнопки мыши вызывалась функция.

Comment: `keyboard` умеет с мышкой работать? В описании модуля (https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) написано, что этим занимается модуль mouse (https://github.com/boppreh/mouse). Попробуйте запустить пример ловли событий мышки и посмотреть возникает он для дополнительных кнопок мышки: https://github.com/boppreh/mouse/blob/master/mouse/__main__.py

Comment: Тогда, пожалуйста, сделайте ответ с решением, что вам помог обработать клики по дополнительной кнопке :)

Comment: Сделал, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение благодаря gil9red.

```
import mouse
def f():
    print(True)
mouse.on_button(f, buttons=('x2'), types=('up'))
```

Где, 'x2' - как раз та самая пятая кнопка.